# nbitcoin получение баланса

Tags: c#, nbitcoin

Пытаюсь получить баланс :

```
var bitcoinPrivateKey = new BitcoinSecret("xxxx");
var network = bitcoinPrivateKey.Network;
var address = bitcoinPrivateKey.GetAddress();

var client = new QBitNinjaClient(network);
var balance = client.GetBalance(address).Result;
```

После некоторого времени выходит ошибка `Произошла одна или несколько ошибок.` на строке `var balance = client.GetBalance(address).Result;`. Самое интересное, что раньше все работало, приват ключ не менял, несколько раз его проверил, он валидный. Где я ошибся ?

Comment: А что у вас в inner exception?

Comment: @AK чет я не понял, поставил исключение и вывод InnerException.Message , а теперь она выводит баланс и исключение не вызывается, с чем такое может быть связано ?

Comment: С какими-нибудь временными сбоями на сервере? Допустим, там был какой-нибудь сервер тайм-аут - а у вас эксепшены не логируются (на будущее наука: сохранять сообщения об ошибках). А теперь уже не воспроизводится и всё, поди узнай, что там было.

Comment: @AK интересно, и часто такое будет ....